# Check if list with given items is present in dict

Tags: python

I have a dict and a list like this:

```
hey = {'2': ['Drink', 'c', 'd'], '1': ['Cook', 'a']}
temp = ['Cook', 'a']
```

I want to check if `temp` is present in `hey`. My code:

```
def checkArrayItem(source,target):
    global flag
    flag = True

    for item in source:
        if (item in target):
            continue
        else:
            flag = False
            break
for i,arr in enumerate(hey) :
    if (len(temp) == len(hey[arr])):
        checkArrayItem(temp,hey[arr])
        if (flag):
            print('I got it')
            break
```

What is a more elegant way to do this check?

Comment: You mean you have a `dict` and a `list`.

Comment: thanks , I had see the link .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `temp in hey.values()`?

Comment: thanks, excellete ans

Comment: @RelaxZeroC: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `set`s to compare to container entirely:

```
In [40]: hey = {'2': ['Drink', 'c', 'd'], '1': ['Cook', 'a']}

In [41]: temp = {'Cook', 'a'}
# This will give you the keys within your dictionary that their values are equal to tamp
In [42]: [k for k, v in hey.items() if set(v) == temp]
Out[42]: ['1']
```

Comment: thanks, it's good to use.